# Draw two-sided arrow on image using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, draw

I want to draw two sided arrow between two points using opencv. I have got one function for single arrow plot which is follows

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
pt1 = (x1, y1)
pt2 = (x2, y2)
cv2.arrowedLine(img_, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 5)
cv2.imshow('Image with arrow', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But is there any method for plotting two sided arrows between two points? I have read the documentation but did not find any. Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well This may not be the best way, but with minimal effort I would use the same `cv2.arrowedLine` method twice with the points order reversed as :

```
cv2.arrowedLine(img_, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 5)
cv2.arrowedLine(img_, pt2, pt1, (0,0,255), 5)
```

Comment: Actually I tried this way already but I was looking for a specific method that can do this for me. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Which versions of opencv have this? I can only find the C++ version of arrowedLine